# See a message in a message

Tags: ros, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm wondering if there is any way to, from the command line only, see a message in a message ?
Here I'm using a message of the type :

```
ObjectData.msg:

Header header
sensor_msgs/Image image_rgb
sensor_msgs/Image image_depth
float32 constant
geometry_msgs/PoseStamped reference_board_pose
geometry_msgs/PoseStamped reference_camera_pose
```

Is there any way to visualize the depth image directly from the command line with something such as :

```
rosrun image_view image_view ...
```

Thanks a lot !

Best,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194442/see-a-message-in-a-message/) by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1172 on 2014-10-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not aware of a way to do this with the current tools.

I would recommend that you write a node which splits off the depth image into its own topic, or write a custom visualizer if you want to view the rgb and depth images in the same viewer.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2014-10-07**:
That's exactly what I'm working on but I was wondering if I could just avoid to do it :). Thanks for the answer.